# How to debug a file that can't treat with it directly?

Tags: process, debug

I have a game that has ("ex: GameGate.exe") file to open.
I found out later that file is not responsible for opening the game directly but it's just a gate to open another file ("ex: GameMain.exe") internally using the `kernel32.CreateProcessInternalA` function.
Also, I found that file "GameMain.exe" among the rest of the game files but when attaching that file to the debugger calls the `ExitProcess` function after a few steps, so I can't debug that file directly.

By the way, I am using `x64dbg`.

How can I debug that file, is there a way to make me debug that file?

Comment: It sounds like `GameGate.exe` implements some protection features, you might want to analyse that one thoroughly first.

Comment: @MegaTonnage: Thank you.

Comment: @LionKing try to pick up a copy of "Anti-Debugging Reference" by Peter Ferrie (who is also a member of this community). Also look into ScyllaHide and TitanHide in conjunction with x64dbg.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Thank you.